# Is there a faster groupby correlation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, pandas-groupby

Hi I am running some python code that calculates the correlation between two columns in my pandas dataframe, while being grouped by date and id. For example, my df looks like this:

```
date id    z      x   y
1    A     z1     x1  y1
1    A     z2     x2  y2
....
....
1    D     z_n-1  x2  y2
1    D     z_n    x2  y2
```

Try not to focus on the subscripts, or what the data actually means. Rather focus on the general form. For a given date, I have multiple repeated observations for a given id and I want to calculate the correlation between "x" and "y" for each id on each date. My df has about 2.4 million rows, which is roughly divided up among 200 dates.

My code to get the correlations obviously works (this seems to be a trivial problem if I wait long enough), but it has been running for about 7 hours now and I'd like to know if anybody has written something that is custom that might run faster? Anyway, here is the code

```
corr_df = df.groupby(['date','id'])['x'].corr(df['y'])
```

Comment: You say this "obviously works" but have you tested it with a smaller dataset? Unable to test right right now but that runtime just doesn't seem right at all. Is your RAM thrashing?

Comment: Also, `groupby` is compiled in Cython so it's highly unlikely that you can target that operation for improvement, but maybe you don't need `groupby`.

Comment: Yes, it works on smaller data sets. I have run this code hundreds of times in the past and always get the desired result.

Comment: My only issue with this data set was its surprising slowness.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar piece of code, and I think that this might be faster:

Try 

`corr_series = df.groupby(['date','id'])[['x','y']].corr()['y'][:,'x']`

This way you don't run the correlation with an external series (external, even if it is just `df` before the grouping), but instead it's calculating the correlation inside the `groupby` object.

Hope it helps.